# Azure Function Proxies that navigate to Angular 9 app on Azure Blob Storage result in mime type errors

Tags: angular, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, angular9

I've hosted multiple Angular 9 apps on one Azure Blob Storage (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942894/hosting-multiple-angular-apps-on-one-azure-blob-storage/62014416?noredirect=1#comment109775533_62014416) - credits to @Sam Erkiner). Now I want to navigate to one of these apps using Azure Function Proxies.
The config is as follows:

```
"proxyname": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/someroute"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myazureblobstorage.z6.web.core.windows.net/folder/subfolder"
        }
```

If I navigate to `https://myazureblobstorage.z6.web.core.windows.net/folder/subfolder` everything works fine.

If I navigate to `https://myazurefunction.azurewebsites.net/someroute` I receive several mime type error messages in the console and the screen remains white. I'm getting three error messages: "Loading module from 'link-to-js-file' was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type ("")"

What can I do to fix these errors and show the angular app? Thanks in advance.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this config :- 

{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "root": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "someRoute",
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "HEAD"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myazureblobstorage.z6.web.core.windows.net/subfolder/index.html",
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
                "response.headers.X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
                "response.headers.X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
                "response.headers.x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
                "response.headers.Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';",
                "response.headers.Referrer-Policy": "same-origin",
                "response.headers.Feature-Policy": "payment 'self'; geolocation 'self'"
            }
        },
        "files": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "someRoute/{filename}.{ext}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "HEAD"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myazureblobstorage.z6.web.core.windows.net/subfolder/{filename}.{ext}"
        },
        "routes": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "someRoute/{*restOfPath}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "HEAD"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myazureblobstorage.z6.web.core.windows.net/subfolder/index.html",
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
                "response.headers.X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
                "response.headers.X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
                "response.headers.x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
                "response.headers.Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';",
                "response.headers.Referrer-Policy": "same-origin",
                "response.headers.Feature-Policy": "payment 'self'; geolocation 'self'"
            }
        },
        "assets": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "someRoute/assets/{file}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "HEAD"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myazureblobstorage.z6.web.core.windows.net/subfolder/assets/{file}"
        },
        "assets-folder-item": {
        "matchCondition": {
              "route": "my-center/assets/{folder}/{item}",
              "methods": [
                "GET",
                "HEAD"
            ]
         },
        "backendUri": "https://myazureblobstorage.z6.web.core.windows.net/folder/subfolder/assets/{folder}/{item}"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the changes you suggested were not successful - the mime type errors are still shown

Comment: can you tell us what mime type errors are you getting? and did you configure assets location like i gave?

Comment: also i have added more configurations for assets, can you please try?

Comment: I configured the proxies exactly like you suggested (even the latest you added) but without success. I don't think it's a routing issue. I'm getting three error messages: "Loading module from '<link-to-js-file>' was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type ("")"

Comment: ohhh, got it. wait updating proxy settings.

Comment: added one more proxy in end, try adding that. if still issue comes please show screenshot of error.

Comment: I added the additional proxy as well but without success. Please find the requested screenshots attached to the original post

Comment: i have update the proxy config, the error was coming due to headers. try this config.

Comment: you used the whole config?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215144/discussion-between-matteroffact-and-aakash-garg).

Comment: For all with the same issue: Additionally to the config shown in Aakash's answer I had to readd the proxyAssetsNameFolderItem proxy (see older version of the answer). I also had to set the baseHref in my index.html to only the innerst subfolder. E.g.: structure on blob: myfolder/mysubfolder -> baseHref =/mysubfolder

Comment: @MatterOfFact, you can edit my answer and i will accept your edit.